# OpenSSL extension for PHP in Ubuntu?

Tags: openssl, php

I'm not sure how to *recompile* PHP with OpenSSL? I've been looking around the OpenSSL PHP page and the OpenSSL tutorials but I don't see any `openssl.so` or `php-openssl.so` around my server?

Is there a simple package on `apt-get` channel so I can install it from there?

I just need to recompile PHP with OpenSSL, but I have no idea how to do this.

EDIT: I run a dedicated server and it's Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Without knowing your distribution and release, there is no way we could tell you if there is an APT repository that would be appropriate to you.

Comment: Sorry, check my edit.

Comment: Check that PHP isn't already compiled with OpenSSL - a lot of default installations have it already. Run phpinfo() and check for the 'OpenSSL' section. Second, if you really need to recompile PHP, copy the ./configure command from phpinfo(), and add `--with-openssl` (or change `--without-openssl` if it is present). You will need your operating system's Development Tools to compile, plus any additional pre-requisites ('dev' files/headers). It is usually preferable to avoid keeping dev tools on a production box. Finally, reinstall the additional extensions you use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a while PHP has had ssl support compliled into it. No extra modules are needed. Check with `phpinfo()`. E.g., on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
$ echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | php 2>&1 |grep -i ssl
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
SSL => Yes
SSL Version => OpenSSL/0.9.8k
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

[libssl1.0.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/libssl1.0.0/filelist) or [libssl-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/libssl-dev/filelist) are probably what you're looking for, though I wonder why you'd need to do this?